# Why does my aliases change to a different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have the following code:

```js
cy.get('input:checkbox').first().as('firstCheckbox').then(() => {

    cy.get('@firstCheckbox').should('be.checked').click()
    cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('not.exist')
    cy.get('@firstCheckbox').should('not.be.checked').click()
    cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('not.exist')
    cy.get('@firstCheckbox').should('be.checked')

})
```

after `cy.get('@firstCheckbox').should('be.checked').click()` the checkbox is moved to the last index position instead of the first.
According to my understanding of aliases this should not matter, because I reference it with `('@')` and it doesn't matter at which position it is. Unfortunately the next `cy.get('@firstCheckbox')` accesses the new first element and not the one I originally referenced. I can't figure it out from the documentation either.
where is the error?

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as

**Update for @agoff:**

it seems to work better with your code but there is a new problem I notice with the new code.
if you uncheck the checkbox then the class is reloaded with js causing it to briefly disappear from the dom. After that it can't find it anymore and the test aborts.
I also tried with reload but it can't find the element anymore. How to deal with this?

the checked checkbox class has the name `custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid`. after unchecking the class name changed to `custom-control-input.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-dirty` for a second and then the element is removed and reloaded to the DOM with with the class name `custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid`. the problem is here that the second `cy.wrap($el)` tries to find the element `custom-control-input.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-dirty` although the initial element with the class `custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid` was searched and found. that's something else I don't understand.

Comment: What do you mean by this line `the checkbox is moved to the last index position instead of the first.` ?

Comment: if i uncheck the checkbox then the index of the element changes from 0 to last position. 
so it is coded on our website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens if during the click event the app removes the input and appends a new one at the end. Then your alias is invalid, because it points to an element no longer in the DOM.

If I **move** the element within the click handler, your code works.

If I **clone** the element within the click handler, your code fails.

**What to do?**

Refresh your alias after the click()

```js
cy.get('input:checkbox').first().as('myCheckbox').then(() => {

  cy.get('@myCheckbox').should('be.checked').click()
    .then(() => cy.get('input:checkbox').last().as('myCheckbox'))  // it's last now!

  cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('be.visible')
  cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('not.exist')

  cy.get('@myCheckbox').should('not.be.checked').click()
    .then(() => cy.get('input:checkbox').last().as('myCheckbox'))

  cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('be.visible')
  cy.get('.globalMessage-display > :nth-child(1) > .alert').should('not.exist')

  cy.get('@myCheckbox').should('be.checked')
})
```

---

The alias command has another trick as well.

If the element is cloned and replaced, the original element becomes **detached from DOM**.

The `cy.get('@alias')` detects detached elements and replays the original command to automatically refresh.

It doesn't work with `.first()` because the element changes position.

But if you use a `data-cy` attribute instead of `.first()`, your code will work.

```js
cy.get('input:checkbox[data-cy="first-checkbox"]')
  .as('myCheckbox').then(() => {

  cy.get('@myCheckbox')
    .should('be.checked').click()    // cloned and moved to another position

  ...

  cy.get('@myCheckbox')                 // detached by previous click
    .should('not.be.checked').click()   // so alias replays original get
                                        // with [data-cy="first-checkbox"]
  ...
  cy.get('@myCheckbox').should('be.checked')  // as above
})
```

Here's the Cypress code that does it

```js
let { subject, alias, command } = aliasObj

const resolveAlias = () => {
  
  if ($dom.isElement(subject)) {          // if this is a DOM element

    const replay = () => {
      cy.replayCommandsFrom(command)
      return undefined
    }

    if ($dom.isDetached(subject)) {     // is it detached?

      subject = subject.filter((index, el) => $dom.isAttached(el))  // all detached?

      if (!subject.length) {
        return replay()                // perform the replay
      }
    }
```

Comment: works pretty well! Ty mate

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing and misusing aliases. When you use the `.then()`, you've already yielded the found element. So, instead of using the alias, you can reference the object directly (after wrapping it). I believe that something like this should fix your problem...

```
cy.get('input:checkbox').then(($el) => {
  cy.wrap($el).should('be.checked').click()
              .and('not.be.checked').click()
              .and('be.checked')
})
```

Comment: updated my initial question

Comment: Updated my answer -- you might be able to get around it by chaining the shoulds (now written as `and()`) instead of re-wrapping the element?

Comment: works but what do I do if I want to run other code between `clicks`? Then the code does not work unfortunately.
and it is not very stable. sometimes it works, sometimes it breaks off after the `clicks` because it is too fast. `.wait` did not help there either

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? My answer was in response to the provided code, and mimics that exact behavior. I think I'm a little confused about what exactly you'd like to do, from start to finish.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i thought the simplified code above would be enough to get a solution. 
I have updated it so that the full extent of the test can be seen.

Comment: When you uncheck the box and it goes to the last index, does checking it always return it back to the first index?

Comment: yes, thats right.